# Can not install wine64 in linux?

Tags: software-installation

[image]

Please explain how I can install `wine64`

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Please copy/paste text from terminal output into your question, instead of screenshots of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a package called `wine64` in the Ubuntu Repositories.

You can install a 64bit version of Wine like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine1.6-amd64
```

Be aware that there are [many caveats with 64bit Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Is_there_a_64_bit_Wine.3F).
There are also [a ton of bugs](https://bugs.winehq.org/buglist.cgi?keywords=win64&resolution=---).

If you want the latest builds, you can install the WineHQ PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Comment: @malekmahmed - You're welcome.  I'm glad this worked for you.  If you're happy with it, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer, by clicking on the little tick mark next to my answer.  :)